Garage Door noise while closing
When my garage door was installed about 5 years ago, it was very quiet. Now it makes quite a noise when opening, especially in the very beginning - here's the video. I lubricated the joints, but nothing changed. The noise seems to be from the wooden parts. Should I worry? Can this be fixed?
I inspected the rollers and the rails, there are no obstructions, the sound seems to be coming form the wooden panels as they rotate when moving.

You have a broken spring. You can see that the two are different lengths due to the one on the right being unsprung, and its left end is resting on the torsion rod.
This means that your opener is working much harder than it should. It may stop working due to excessive force limits. Its components are wearing faster, too.
You need to replace both springs with new ones of the proper coil count and wire diameter. This is critical, as the wrong springs will not maintain appropriate force throughout the cycle.
Note that these springs carry tremendous force, and you should not work on them until you have a good understanding of the danger and safe strategy.

